# Set URL to dynamic URL in JSF

Tags: jsf

I'm currently working on a project in JSF which is an e-commerce application.
Is there any way to make the url for the products dynamic for Ex:

- the url or a product looks like this
  `http://localhost:9080/pindiv-web/store/product.jsf`
- I want it to look like this url
  `http://localhost:9080/pindiv-web/store/product-name/`
  is it possible to do it in JSF ?
  i already looked over Pretty-faces but couldn't find something useful

Comment: yes, prettyfaces supports this but the url might need to include one more path

Comment: @Kukeltje oh really do you have any tutorial or example i can follow and no problem for including one more path